# How to copy image file from Temporary Internet Files (From IE) folder to C:\Test\test.jpg in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file, copy

when you visit a website image file store in Temporary Internet Files in IE.

I will copy a image file from this folder to C:\test.jpg by vb.net in visual studio 2010

please help me.